table.el table not realigning after editing cell contents
I inserted the following table:
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+

I then entered some data into a cell, which caused the columns to become misaligned:
+-----+-----+-----+
| Type     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+

The Org manual says that I can re-align the columns automatically by pressing TAB, RET and C-c C-c inside the table, but none of these work for me.
When I try C-c C-c, I get the following message:

Use 'C-c `' to edit table.el tables

But when I try 'C-c `', I get an error message:

Not at a table

This post on Stackoverflow describes the same problem, but none of the suggested solutions worked for me.
I have only been using Emacs for a couple of days, so I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm using Emacs 29.4 on Windows 10. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

In the context of Org, a table typically means an Org-table.  This type of table is what Org users use for  formula  (=*TBLFM*) and stuff.  And it is these types of tables that you can do automatic align with TAB etc.
What you have with you is a table.el table.  And table.el is a totally different library, and pre-dates Org-'s org-table.el library.
TLDR: What you have is a donkey (=table.el),  and mistaking it for a horse(=org-table.el) you are doing horse stuff with the donkey.  Horses and donkeys look alike, but they aren't the same.

This is a table.el table

+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+
|     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+


* This is an `Org` table


|---+---|
|   |   |
|---+---|
|   |   |
|---+---|
|   |   |
|---+---|


* How to tell them apart?

An `org`-table begins and ends with a `|` (= `pipe` character).

A `table.el`-table may start and end with non-pipe characters. 



Editing table.el table in `Org' mode
In an Org-mode, I entered M-x table-insert, and inserted the below table.  Subsequently, I did C-c ' to edit the table.
From Packages that Org cooperates with (Hint: See towards the end of the page)
table.el by Takaaki Ota
Complex ASCII tables with automatic line wrapping, column- and row-spanning, and alignment can be created using the Emacs table package by Takaaki Ota.  Org mode recognizes such tables and exports them properly.  C-c ' to edit these tables in a special buffer, much like Org's code blocks.  Because of interference with other Org mode functionality, Takaaki Ota tables cannot be edited directly in the Org buffer.

C-c ' (org-edit-special): Edit a table.el table.  Works when point is in a table.el table.

C-c ~​ (org-table-create-with-table.el): Insert a table.el table.  If there is already a table at point, this command converts it between the table.el format and the Org mode format.  See the documentation string of the command org-convert-table for the restrictions under which this is possible.




I see, thank you for the link to the table.el source. The comments there mention that table.el tables re-align dynamically as content is typed into them, but that is not the case for me. I have used M-x table-fixed-width-mode to make sure that fixed-with-mode is disabled.

Updated my earlier response with a screnshot and a link to manpage.

I'm so sorry, I had been trying C-C ` (backtick) instead of C-c ' (apostrophe)! Thank you for the link to the man page, the screenshots and your patience :) Happy New Year!

Since the answer seems to have answered your question, please accept it.
